# Updating a joined table PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

In MySQL I know its possible to select from two tables that have been joined, but is it possible to update the same two tables using a join? Or will I have to update each table individually?

Comment: What engine are you using?  If it's InnoDB do you have cascade updates turned on?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to post. Its a MySQL database.

Comment: It's okay, you did put it in the title, but that isn't exactly what he wants Chris! He is referring to this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-engines.html

Comment: It is MyIsam if I'm not mistaken. Thanks for the clarification Thiago

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, e.g.

```
UPDATE table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.id = t1.id -- Your keys.
SET t1.column = '...', t2.column = '...' -- Your Updates
WHERE ... -- Your conditional
```

Comment: You my friend are a genius. Thank you kindly!